# Screen extends past monitor edges

Tags: windows-7, resolution, hdmi, projector

My media center has no regular monitor; it is connected to a 1280*720 projector using an HDMI cable. On Linux and Windows XP, this works just fine, but with Windows 7 the image extends a good 25 pixels beyond the physical edge of the display, on all 4 sides.

I have checked that I have the correct video driver (it's an on-board Intel chip) and I have correctly set it to 1280*720. When I do this, almost the entire height of the taskbar is hidden.

When I use either the built-in settings or the Intel settings to adjust the display to full HD 1920*1080, the projector automatically scales the image down to its native resolution, and the result matches the physical edges perfectly. But of course it makes the image fuzzy and text is tiny, so it's not ideal for a media center.

Why is Windows 7 messing this up, and how can I fix it?

Comment: It's called "overscan". Normally this is a problem with the TV. But in your case, you probably caused it by an "improper" configuration of MCE. IIRC the display device triggers this overscan by MCE. Redo the MCE setup, and try a different device selection.  See http://www.avsforum.com/forum/26-home-theater-computers/1373666-how-correct-hidden-overscan-windows-media-center.html

Comment: This is not about the Media Center suite. The problem occurs even at the normal desktop, when MCE has not been started.